# Online survey with free-hand sketches

Tags: gratis, drawing, survey

I am looking for a free online survey tool that has the ability for participants to draw free-hand sketches. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm late to the party but you can do this with a [PollUnit Survey](https://pollunit.com/en/survey). See attached image which shows an example of a drawing step.

[image]

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit