# Free survey web application which provides easily printable single access codes

Tags: web-apps, survey

Is there any free survey web application which provides printed single access codes?

I have seen that [Sogo Survey](http://www.sogosurvey.com) supports this, but this requires a paid upgrade.

[image]

So I am looking for a free alternative.

P.S. I posted this question on webapps.sx some time ago, but it was considered as off topic and deleted. I hope it is on topic here. If not, please make a suggestion where to ask.

Scenario:

- In the webapp, survey owner generates 50 unique codes, and is given a convenient way to print them on sheets of paper
- Survey owner distributes the unique codes to 50 persons, for instance at a conference
- Each of the 50 persons goes to the website, logs in using their code, and completes the survey

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is looking for [a place to host a service](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic), not for software. The bounty was refunded.

Comment: @Gilles No it is not looking for a place to host a service. I am asking for a web application! That's something totally different!

Comment: You asked: “Is there any free online survey service”. Services are off-topic, what's on-topic is software. Looking for software you can install on a server is on-topic. Looking for services that somebody offers, and may or may not implement via software, is off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps this is software as a service ? ;-)

Comment: @Gilles See Ben Millers answer in your link to meta. Asking for a web app blog with special software features is on topic. This is essentially the same as asking for a survey web app with special software features.

Comment: @Gilles By the way there are other questions on this site about online survey software which are not closed! For example: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/online-survey-with-free-hand-sketches?rq=1 or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13771/online-survey-which-can-filter-results-based-on-demographic-questions?rq=1

Comment: See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations and http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications

Comment: @Gilles: The meta discussion you linked to is about hosting ("*hosting for Laravel*"). This meta discussion is more appropriate for the present question: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/255/can-i-answer-with-website-webapp

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I recently did a search for another question here on Software Recommendations, see [Online survey to be installed on my host](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20995/14982), where I [suggested](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/21267/14982) to look into [JDeSurvey](http://github.com/JD-Software/JDeSurvey), and when looking a bit more into the [features](//github.com/JD-Software/JDeSurvey/wiki/Features#sharing) of this survey tool I found the following on sharing the surveys:

> ### Sharing
>
> #### Publishing Surveys
>
> Once a survey has been designed it is ready to be filled out by participants. Publishing and sharing your surveys requires no effort. Just click an option to publish and start collecting responses from participants.
>
> Each published survey is assigned a unique URL that can be provided to participants so they may access them through a web browser.
>   Published surveys can be embedded and displayed within web sites.
>   The process of filling out surveys is simple, direct, and straightforward.
>
> #### Generate QR Barcodes
>
> Use QR Barcodes as an alternative method for publishing surveys.
>
> A QR code can instantly be obtained for any survey.
>   Copy, save, print, and post QR codes for participants to scan with their mobile device to start filling out surveys.
>
> #### Survey Email Invitations
>
> Grant survey participants to fulfill surveys by sending out email invitations. This handsome feature allows you to deliver surveys in bulk to groups of participants. Compared to sending out surveys one-by-one to each participant separately email invitations decreases the time by a significant amount
>
> Send out survey invitations to multiple users at once via email using comma delimited files.
>   Check the number of email invitations sent out along with the number of email invitations opened by recipients.

In other words, instead of printing access codes, you could print out either unique URLs to hand out, or you could print out QR codes to be scanned by their mobile devices. Or maybe not so good, email a group with survey invitations.

I have *not* tried this tool myself, and I'm not a 100% sure it can provide multiple URLs for a given survey, but it is worth taking a look, I recon.

**Edit:** In the [faq](http://www.jdsoft.com/faq/faqs.php) section there are descriptions on how to create internal/external users, and how change from a public to a private survey, so it should be possible to create the printed access code stuff using external users.

Comment: @Thanks. The problem with this is that it seems that I have to install it manually. So I need to find additionally a free host which is able to host this. I guess that this is to much work, so I probably stick to sdaps. However since there are no  easier solutions you get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know about [GoogleSurveys](http://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/home)?

[This answer on WebApps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70822) says, that it is possible to avoid the same user filling out the Google form twice, but it requires the participants to log into their Google accounts.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted "**printed** single access codes". And it should not be required to have a Google account.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I must've missed that part. I sadly don't have much experience with surveys so I don't know which services provide *printed single access codes*. But this definitely is the right place to ask. Someone here will know about such a service.